# What is the correct way to toggling a filter on a json array?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have an array of json objects, and I want to be able to show either all of them, or remove some of them by filtering them by a key value.

I achieved this by creating a new constant:

```
const filtered = data.filter((item) => item.highVariance === false);
```

And a different constant:

```
const showHighVar = isHighVar ? data : filtered;
```

And then I have a checkbox that lets me toggle the shotHighVar constant in:

```
input type="checkbox" onChange={() => setHighVar(!isHighVar)}/>
```

In order to map it later in code:

```
{sorted(showHighVar).slice(0, 25 * pageIndex).map((x) => (...))}
```

But it seems to me like there should be a better way of doing this, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it. the one thing that i would change is that instead of creating `filtered` variable all the time just filter the data when `isHighVar` is false. So your code should look something like this -

```
const showHighVar = isHighVar ? data : data.filter((item) => item.highVariance === false);

{sorted(showHighVar).slice(0, 25 * pageIndex).map((x) => ( .....))}
```

Or when you are running the `map` function after sorting and slicing. just add a if statement in `map` function and check if `isHighVar` is false then return null else do whatever you are doing.

eg.

```
{sorted(data).slice(0, 25 * pageIndex).map((x) => {
  if(isHighVar===false && x.highVariance!==false){
      return null; 
  }

  ....

})}
```